# Apache eCharts - custom dot within existing chart

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

I want to display a single marker (the DOT on the image below) over an existing chart somewhere. The chart is made with Apache Echarts and in my case it is a stacked Barchart - but I guess that might not even matter for rendering the dot.

Can this dot be done with a custom chart in Apache Echarts somehow? I've checked all the examples and couldn't find anything similar.

[image: barcharat with custom dot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. Basically you can create a eChart-**series** for a **line-chart**. As long as it has just one data-point no lines are displayed (of course - where would they go). So a line chart with a single value ends up being displayed as a single dot.

I ended up with 4 series, 3 for my stacked bar-chart and a 4th one that just ends up displaying the point.

```
{
...
  series: [
  ...,
   {
     name: 'whatever',
     type: 'line',
     data: [44]
   }
  ] 
}
```